# Highcharts - Ignore totals row in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts to create a bar chart, it is getting its data from a DataTable and I wondering how I can get highcharts to ignore the totals row in the table when creating the graph.

This is my code for the Highcharts:

```
//HighCharts
        function BarChart() {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                data: {
                    table: document.getElementById('dataTable')

                },
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'By Category Results'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Units'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

The totals row I wish to ignore for the graph is the first row in the table.

Comment: You can clone your table and in the cloned table remove the totals column. Then use this in generating your chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `startRow` attribute in your `data` option. If your total is the first row, you can set `startRow: 1` (the default is `0`), and that should skip the totals row.

Here's where `startRow` is mentioned in the Highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.startRow

I hope this helps!